# The request object is accessed in the JSTL tag via pageContext

Tags: jstl, pagecontext

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:if test="${"POST".equalsIgnoreCase(pageContext.request.method) && pageContext.request.getParameter("submit") !=null}">
</c:if>
```

This code segment I am getting this error. Please help me with this issue.
Multiple annotations found at this line:

- EL Syntax Error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have embedded some double quotes inside the test string.

You should replace them by single quotes.

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <c:if test="${'POST'.equalsIgnoreCase(pageContext.request.method) && pageContext.request.getParameter('submit') !=null}">
 </c:if>
```

Comment: Not working sir. Still getting an error."The method getEqualsIgnoreCase() is undefined for the type String".